# About JavaScript call function

Tags: javascript

I want to ask a little question about JavaScript `call()` function. I've started to learn JavaScript into the depths, and I just can't understand it.why with this example I'm getting result :

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

And With this I'm getting error.:

```
var args = Array.prototype.call(arguments);
```

both of these functions exist within `__proto__` of Array, as i know Array is extend Function. In this example returns true `Array.__proto__ === Function.prototype`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type:

```
typeof(Array.prototype.slice)
> "function"
```

(this is a function and you can use `call` - see `Function.prototype.call` )

```
typeof(Array.prototype)
> "object"
```

(this is not a function and you can't use `call` - "*can't see*" `Object.prototype.call` )

Comment: @Victorino what don't you understand? You can only `call` a function and `Array.prototype` is not a function. What part of that is confusing you you, specifically.

Answer (score 4):

`call` is a method of a function. `Array.prototype.slice` is a function but `Array.prototype` is not so it doesn't have the `call` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.__proto__ === Function.prototype
```

Hehe. I think you've stumbled upon some internal implementation, that's not actually how it works. Depending on your actual experience with Computer Science / Software Engineering I'm tempted to suggest to ignore this particularly artefact.

Prototype is an instance of Object class, and they don't have `call` method (unless it's defined by user or library). So, `Whatever.prototype.call` should invoke an error as expected.

Another perculiar behavior:

Object instanceof Function
// -> true
Function instanceof Object
// -> true

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will take it into consideration. as i now about a prototype chain, this is going like this `Array ->> Function ->> Object`, ore i missing some thing?